# Модель, интерфейс, свервис

Tags: javascript, typescript

я начинающий веб-разработчик и на данный момент прохожу тестовое задание для вступления в компанию. Суть проблемы заключается в том, что тест оказался чуть сложнее чем я ожидал и хотел бы уточнить пару моментов.

Мне нужно написать сервис, модель и интерфейс для работы с товарами на сайте, но суть задачи плохо понятна) Может кто подсказать, что именно надо сделать или дать ссылку на конкретный пример, чтобы я точно понял свою задачу? Заранее спасибо.

P.S в гугле уже рылся, особенно "модель" искал, но там одни вебкам модели были)

Answer (score 1):

Почитай про [MVC](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/simplified-explanation-to-mvc-5d307796df30), от тебя требуют его понимания.

Если совсем коротко, то на примере твоей задачи:

1. Интерфейс -- это html-представление твоего компонента (верстка)
2. Модель -- это объектное представление сущностей приложения
3. Сервис -- это функционал, посредством которого твои модели взаимодействуют между собой.

---

Как это выглядит на практике

- **Интерфейс**:

  `<div class="user ${user.isActive ? 'isActive' : ''}"> 
     <img src="${user.ava}"> 
     <h2 class="name">${user.name}</h2>
  </div>`
- **Модель:**:

  `class User{
     private isActive: boolean;
     constructor(public ava: string, public name: string){}
  } 
  class UserGallery{
     public users: User[]
  }`
- **Сервис**:

  `class UserService{
     loadUsers(urs: string){...}
     removeUser(i: number){...}
     addUser(u: User){...}
     toggleUserActive(u: User){...}
  }`

Comment: Нужно добавить, что речь, скорее всего, идет о современных библиотеках/фреймворках [Angular/React/Vue] и понимании того, как примерно с ними работать